# Como bloquear o console do navegador usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, console

Gostaria de saber como bloquear o usuário de executar scripts pelo console do navegador.

Comment: Qual o objetivo de bloquear o uso do console? (ou das devtools)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Edit: esse código não funciona mais no Google Chrome.**

---

Na verdade, é possível bloquear o console do Google Chrome assim como o Facebook anda fazendo, com o seguinte código:

```
var _z = console;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'console', {
    get: function(){
        if (_z._commandLineAPI) {
            throw new Error('console bloqueado');
        }
        return _z;
    },
    set: function(val) {
        _z = val;
    }
});
```

Abra o console do Google Chrome na página do Facebook e veja você mesmo (não aparece para todos os usuários):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Referências:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-browsers-integrated-developer-tools
- http://kspace.in/blog/2013/02/22/disable-javascript-execution-from-console/

Comment: Tenho a impressão de que *isso não funciona*: primeiro por experiência própria, pois já mexi muito com isso (fazendo bookmarklets por exemplo); segundo que algumas funções do console não liberadas na `Window`, sendo adicionadas na execução do comando. A segurança contra `setInverval` do Facebook ainda pode ser facilmente contornada. De fato isso é mais um aviso contra scamming e abuso de algumas funções.

Comment: Teste você mesmo. O console não funciona. Mas dá para usar um bookmarklet ou injetar script pela barra de endereços.

Comment: O Facebook só está bloqueando o console para alguns usuários, aleatoriamente. Aquela mensagem é exibida assim que você abre o console. Veja: https://www.facebook.com/selfxss

Comment: Retiro o que eu disse, esse efeito parece ser aleatório, não funcionando apenas em alguns casos. De fato parece ser facilmente contornável por desenvolvedores, como no exemplo do `setInterval`, porém não por usuários comums.

Comment: É facilmente contornável: clique em `<page context>` e mude o contexto para alguma extensão, então altere o script como se fosse uma extensão. Isso não impede quase nenhum scammer.

Comment: Você normalmente não tem acesso ao `Window` em uma extensão, mas há essa alternativa: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1638855/1850091

Comment: *1.* mude o contexto para uma extensão; *2.* `localStorage.consoleEnabled='opt';location.reload();` O console será ativado.

Comment: Acredito que isso seja apenas uma pedrinha no caminho de alguns usuários iniciantes com o console, porém a maioria dos que abrem o console é porque sabem o que estão fazendo e facilmente saberiam contornar esta solução, por isso concordo com a resposta do @GuilhermeBernal

Comment: Legal a resposta lá no SO: " sou engenheiro de segurança no Facebook e isso é culpa minha..."

Answer (score 14):

Não é possível. A página é submissa ao navegador e o console de javascript não é algo que você possa realmente controlar, é um extra. Seria como impedir que vissem o seu html ou criar um arquivo .txt que não pudesse ser editado, não faz sentido.

O usuário é completamente livre para editar **qualquer coisa** da sua página. Qualquer código pode ser alterado e qualquer validação feita puramente em JS pode ser burlada. É por isso que o servidor nunca deve confiar em algo vindo do cliente.

Comment: A meio de comparação você não pode nem proteger variáveis, uma vez que o usuário - tendo ferramentas para isso e sabendo usar as - pausar completamente a execução do código e acessar elas. // Porém, se quiser evitar que extensões acessem dados do script: é possível.

Comment: +1 o melhor que pode ser feito é não utilizar variáveis globais, remover referencias que possam estar no objeto de elementos do DOM, em suma encapsular bem o código e manter os contextos escondidos, aplicar minificação para atrapalhar na hora de depurar o código. Nenhuma solução impede, mas evita os menos experientes a manipulação de código.

Answer (score 3):

Desculpe ai pessoal, mas quanto ao resposta sobre o Facebook estar desabilitando o console somente exibindo aquela mensagem. Não confere.

O que o Facebook faz é simplesmente exibindo um aviso para o usuário não usar o console e para isso exibe a mansagem usando o objeto console no Javascripr. Eu faço isso nos meus projetos para criar uma assinatura que é exibida no console. Vejam o que faço no Javasript principal do site:

```
style = "color:blue;font-size:1.1em;";
style2 = "color:green; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.1em;";
console.groupCollapsed("Creditos do desenvolvedor:");
   console.info("%c-------------------------------------------------------------",style);
   console.info("%cEste é mais um site desenvolvido pela...", style2);
   console.info("%chttp://www.site.com.br",style);
   console.info("%cTodos os direitos reservados © 2017",style);
   console.info("%c-------------------------------------------------------------",style);
   console.info("");
console.groupEnd();
```