# Como desabilitar opções do Developer Tools no Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, navegador-de-internet

Supostamente o Facebook usa um código parecido com este que esta no link http://snapbuilder.com/code_snippets/snippet.php?sid=174&printable=1 para desativar e colocar um aviso para seus usuários. Já que o código do link acima parece estar pela metade.

1. Como proceder para resolver a questão exposta?
2. É possível desativar as outras opções como: `Elements` e `Sources`.

Comment: Quais opções você do Developer Tools você quer desabilitar? Pois no Facebook eu consegui utilizar o DT sem problemas.

Comment: No FB a opção Console esta personalizada queria saber se é fácil modificar isso? eu quero fazer o mesmo nas abas Elements e Sources se possível

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6035/como-bloquear-o-console-do-navegador-usando-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade o developer tools não é desativado, mas o Facebook desencoraja a fazer alguma coisa lá, já que muitos usuários leigos não sabem do que se trata.

Eles passaram a exibir essa mensagem por causa de usuários mal-intencionados que instruem pessoas a executar códigos em seus navegadores e que poderiam potencialmente roubar dados dos usuários.

Pesquisei aqui, e o código que exibe a mensagem é relativamente simples:

```
var i = "Stop!",
    j = "This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy-paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or \"hack\" someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.";

if ((window.chrome || window.safari)) {
    var l = 'font-family:helvetica; font-size:20px;';
    [
       [i, l + 'font-size:50px; font-weight:bold; ' + 'color:red; -webkit-text-stroke:1px black;'],
       [j, l],
       ['', '']
    ].map(function(r) {
        setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, '\n%c' + r[0], r[1]));
    });
}
```

Basicamente, o que o código acima faz é exibir uma mensagem no console quando for detectado que o mesmo foi aberto.

Fonte: [Console.log without reference to the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587201/console-log-without-reference-to-the-script)

Answer (score 2):

Não tem como desabilitar, apenas exibir uma mensagem no console que da a impressão de estar desabilitado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Object.defineProperty(window, "console", {
                value: console,
                writable: false,
                configurable: false
            });

            var i = 0;
            function showWarningAndThrow() {
                if (!i) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log("%cWarning message", "font: 2em sans-serif; color: yellow; background-color: red;");
                    }, 1);
                    i = 1;
                }
                throw "Console is disabled";
            }

            var l, n = {
                set: function (o) {
                    l = o;
                },
                get: function () {
                    showWarningAndThrow();
                    return l;
                }
            };
            Object.defineProperty(console, "_commandLineAPI", n);
            Object.defineProperty(console, "__commandLineAPI", n);
            showWarningAndThrow();
        </script>
```

Fonte: [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692646/how-does-facebook-disable-the-browsers-integrated-developer-tools)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome envolve todo o código do console em:

```
with ((console && console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
  <code goes here>
}
```

... Por isso o site redefine console._commandLineAPI com:

```
Object.defineProperty(console, '_commandLineAPI',
   { get : function() { throw 'Nããão!' } })
```

Qualquer dúvida, brinque com isso:

```
function escape(s) {


  Object.defineProperty(console, 'foo', 
     { get : function() { throw 'Nãão!' } });

  var code = 'with((window.console && console.foo) || {}) {\n\t'+s+'\n}';
  console.log(code);

  try {
    console.log(eval(code));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```