# Como descobrir se o console do navegador está aberto?

Tags: javascript, console

Existe alguma maneira de capturar a informação de que o console do navegador está aberto? Atualmente eu faço um script que verifica se a altura do navegador foi alterada... mas no caso dele desgrudar o console do navegador, ou mesmo, modificar para a lateral, o script não captura.

A ideia é que quando a pessoa abrir o console, o conteúdo da página será apagado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com essa resposta: [Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open). Uma das formas de fazer é a que você está utilizando. A outra é a seguinte:

```
var devtools = /./;
devtools.toString = function() {
    this.opened = true;
}

console.log('%c', devtools);
// devtools.opened vai se tornar true quando o console estiver aberto
```

Segundo ele, essa solução se utiliza do fato de que o método toString() não é chamado quando você utiliza o browser com o console fechado.

Comment: legal, existe uma maneira de fechar o console.log?

Comment: Acredito que isso não é possível porque você estaria interferindo na forma de funcionamento do browser.

Comment: Isso funciona para demais navegadores? A pergunta que você linkou menciona o Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @JulianoNunes, você pode criar uma função para isso, pois a variável continuará com o valor `true` se o usuário abrir o console e fechá-lo em seguida. Assim, você poderá executá-la sempre que for verificar se o Console está aberto ou não. Então, você pode fazer:

```
// set interval que testa se o console está aberto
setInterval(function(){
  document.body.innerText = isDevtoolsOpened();
}, 1000);

// função que faz a verificação
function isConsoleOpened() {

  let devtools = /./;
  devtools.toString = function() {
      this.opened = true;
  }

  console.log("%c", devtools);

  return devtools.opened ? true : false;

}
```

Cabe lembrar, também, que se a função `console.log()` for sobrescrita, como no [stacksnippets](https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1), isso não irá funcionar, uma vez que a função poderá ser disparada a qualquer momento, independente se o Console estiver aberto ou não.

Fechar o console [parece não ser possível](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961938/how-to-close-console-in-chrome-using-javascript#comment59579825_35961938), afinal seria uma falha de segurança dos navegadores deixarem os desenvolvedores efetuar esse processo. [Antigamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6035/como-bloquear-o-console-do-navegador-usando-javascript) poderia bloquear o acesso à ele, um recurso que o Facebook havia criado, mas já está defasado.

Comment: valeu pela resposta, mas nem precisei muito disso, chamei o método que precisava dentro do `devtools.toString = function() { ... }`.